# Google Places API questions

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

I'm working on a mobile app project that uses `Google Places APIs` and have some questions:

1. From my research in Google documentation, they allow `FREE` and `UNLIMITED` use of their `Google Places API` data when used by Android devices. Currently, my development team is accessing `Google Places Web Services API` for all API calls. For the Android devices, should I have them change to use `Google Places API for Android` in order to take advantage of this?
2. I read in Google's API policy that they may allow for caching of API data (with limitations - i.e. you must refresh every 30 days, etc) if you want to increase performance of your code and/or use in offline mode, etc. However, it says you must get their permission for caching from Google. I cannot find *how* or *where* to request this permission. Would be helpful if you can point me in the right direction with a form or a link or something.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The Google Places API for Android is not unlimited . https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage  and can you please give a link for your second statement? I somehow have missed this information from their documentation.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. This is why I am confused and coming here. Regarding usage limits... see the link you sent me, second paragraph titled "Summary - what you need to do". First sentence reads: "Usage of the Google Places API for Android is free and unlimited for all apps."

Comment: The caching item is from this link: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/usage    the section titled "Ensure that your app complies with the API Terms of Service" -- see the 3rd bullet point.

Comment: Regarding point 1. The Google Place API is Free but not "unlimited" readily. If you are happy with 1000 requests per 24 hours, then its fine. But if your app requires more, then you have to prove your identity by providing your billing details, though they will not charge you anything, but the limit will be increased to 150000 requests per 24 hours, if you need more then you have to contact them. You still won't  be charged.

Comment: Oh ok. That is interesting. Its really confusing in the developers console. I see that the free quota is 1000 and i proved my identity so it raised my quota to 150,000 but because only the 1000 is described there as 'free'... it makes me think i'll get charged starting at 1001'st hit. You saying that is not the case (I haven't crossed the 1000 mark yet but trying to plan costs i may incur)? Thanks again!